# Can magisk replace files outside of /data/system?

Tags: rooting, magisk, systemless-root

I need to replace a file in /data/data/... Is it possible with magisk? And if so, how?

I've read the developer guide multiple times, and it seems that it's possible using an [overlay system](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/guides.html#root-directory-overlay-system) - which I absolutely fail to understand.

Another way of replacing the file could theoretically be using shell during the module's installation process, but that gives me "operation not permitted" (+ it's not an "overlay" because we're directly modifying the file).

Comment: yes the main purpose of Magisk is to have read-write access to /data. the concept of overlay concerns /system (not /data)

Comment: How would you replace `/data/data/file.txt` then? I tried creating a directory in the module's installer with the same structure as the file I am trying to replace (`data/data/file.txt`) and then in `customize.sh` created a variable `REPLACE="/data/data/file.txt"`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not experienced in writing Magisk modules (what your actual concern is), but writing to `/data` is not a problem once you have root access. E.g. you can run a script on boot, or execute commands manually from commandline, or perform operations from a GUI root-enabled app and read/write/delete whatever you want in whole `/data` partition. `systemless`, `overlay` and bind-mount things are for read-only OS partitions i.e. `/system`, `/vendor` etc. `/data` has ever been writable. That's where the Android OS itself stores data. And that's where users store data.